# Can someone please help me read this Kanji character? (picture included)

Tags: translation

My friend posted this and I wanted to know what it means. I can read hiragana and katakana and I know the first and last syllables read "MA-DA-_____-TAI"

I can't read the Kanji in the middle. Can someone help me?? thank you!! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QflU.png)

Answer (score 4):

it's NE(寝).

"ma-da-ne-ta-i".

It means, "I want to sleep more"(I don't want to wake up yet)

BTW, how about using Google Translator's handwriting function from next time?
You can draw Kanjis by your mouse. It's very cool.
[image]